# Why does the case of the all-Flag for add and commit differ?

Tags: git, arguments

Can anybody tell me, why does the **case** of the all-Flag shortcut for `git add`

```
-A           //higher case
--all  
--no-ignore-removal
```

and `git commit`

```
-a           //lower case
--all
```

differ?

**Edit:**
This is what I'm talking about.
[image]

&

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those `-a` are for two different scenario:

- The [`git commit -a`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) does a `git add -u` (update).
- the [`git add -A`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) does a `git add` + a `git add -u`.

That means:

- a `commit -a` commit every additions/removal already done to the index, and ignore the working tree new files.
  It is about **reading the index only, not the working tree**.
- `add -A` adds to the index everything.
  It is about **updating the index, using the working tree**.

---

`git add --all` was introduced in [commit 3ba1f11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ba1f114267b19a458df0f1d714dc4010ec9cc56) in July 2008 (git 1.6.0).

The comment was:

> People sometimes find that "`git add -u && git add .`" are 13 keystrokes too many.
>   This reduces it by nine.
>
> It will be too much of a change that is against the expectation of the existing users to allow "`git commit -a`" to include untracked files, and it would be inconsistent if we named this new option "`-a`", so the short option is "`-A`".
>   We *might* want to later add "`git commit -A`" but that is a separate topic.

---

`git commit --all` was documented in [commit 130fcca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/130fcca63fe8e7e087e7419907e018cbbaf434a3) (February 2006, git 1.2.0)

> "`git commit --all`" can run from a subdirectory, but it updates the index with all the modified files and does a whole tree commit.

---

So `git commit -a` was introduced *before* `git add -A`, and was not including new files.
Hence the difference:

**`-A` is there to remind the `--all` for `git add` isn't the same as the `--all` for `git commit`**.

Comment: I think you got it wrong. I know what the commands do, I'm just wondering why the cases differ. -A vs. -a.

Comment: @FranzEbner for me `-A` and `-a` are the same for `git add`. And there is no `-A` for `git commit`.

Comment: @FranzEbner I have edited the answer with more explanation about the difference.

Comment: I edited my question to show even more, that I'm not asking about the functionality.

Comment: @FranzEbner I have edited my answer: `-A` (for `git add`) is there to remind the `--all` for `git add` isn't the same as the `--all` for `git commit`.

Comment: Somehow I over-read the quintessence of your previous edit, the answer was already clear then. Thank you!

Comment: @FranzEbner yes, my initial answer wasn't very clear. Hopefully, that last edit helped.